# Adding item to a collection property of an entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC 5 project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

I need to handle a situation when an `ApplicationUser` who is a student is supposed to join a study group after registration to the system, if he fills in a registration code (only used to join a study group) he has been provided.

The problem is that when I try to add an item to `StudyGroup` property `ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members` I get the

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Registration action:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            { 
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Name = model.Name,
                Surname = model.Surname
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Student");

                var group =
                    (from g in db.StudyGroups
                     where g.RegistrationCode == model.GroupCode
                     select g).FirstOrDefault();

                if (group != null)
                {
                    user.StudyGroup.Add(group);
                    group.Members.Add(user);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**ApplicationUser:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudyGroup> StudyGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

**StudyGroup:**

```
public class StudyGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int StudyGroupId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Group Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registration Code", Description = "The code which students will use to join this study group.")]
    public string RegistrationCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my **Model Builder** for StudyGroup:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudyGroup>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Members)
            .WithMany(m => m.StudyGroup);
```

What should be the right way to add these items to the properties of the entities and why isn't the approach of mine working, please? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not initializing the `ICollection<StudyGroup> StudyGroup` property on your User?

Try adding a default constructor which initializes the property:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() 
    {
        this.StudyGroup = new List<StudyGroup>();
        this.Tests = new List<Test>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudyGroup> StudyGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```